# Youtube Python API: Login status

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am using the sample code to login to youtube:

```
def auth(email, password):
# Setup service.
    yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    yt_service.email = email
    yt_service.password = password
    yt_service.source = 'youtube_interface'
    yt_service.developer_key = DEVELOPER_KEY

    # Login.
    yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()

    return yt_service
```

Please tell me, how can I know if the login is successful or not? And how to logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing new development in Python, I'd recommend using v3 of the API instead. The legacy Python client library you're using hasn't been updated in a while, and is still going against v1 of the API. There are some code samples for using Python with v3 at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python

That being said, to answer your question, if the ClientLogin attempt fails, the client library will raise an error. And I'm not aware of a way of programmatically invalidating a ClientLogin token to "log out". The token will just expire after a number of hours.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I did not use V3 of the API because the label 'Experimental' makes me feel a little bit uncomfortable.